# Bootstrap sass nav dropdown doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code but the collapse button when clicked doesn't activate the dropdown. I have javascript working in other areas of my app, but the nav button isn't functional. Here's a link to my project: https://github.com/parisliahyun/citibikeapp

Here's my code:

_header.html.erb:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

   <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->       
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
      <% if logged_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to "Awesome Citi", root_path %> </li>
      <li><%= link_to "My Account", account_path %> </li>
      <li><%= link_to "New Search", new_search_path %> </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Saved Destinations", user_path(current_user) %></li>
      <li><a href="http://citibikenyc.com/stations"target="_blank">Station Map</a></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Logout', session_path, :method => :delete %> </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

application.js:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Awesome Citi</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header'%>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Including JQuery and Bootstrap.js in the `<head></head>` fixes this issue.

For some reason it only happens when you include the js at the bottom of the before.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this also for about two weeks and I'm pretty sure it's related to the data-target in your _header.html.erb file. Try:

```
`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex1-collapse">`
```

and:

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex1-collapse">`

You need to associate the button with the div by giving them the same id.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using the CDNs for jQuery and bootstrap.js.

Simply add this to your html:

> ```
> <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
> ```

You can of course link to your local scripts but this is a fast solution.